# Retrieve the value of first cell in the row and Column when a cell value change in that row

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following in a macro to add a comment when a cell value is changed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Const xRg As String = "C4:AK100"
Dim strOld As String
Dim strNew As String
Dim strCmt As String
Dim strCmt2 As String
Dim Cell As Range
Dim rngComm As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet`your text`
Dim c As Range
Dim Comment As CommentThreaded
With Target(1)
If Intersect(.Cells, Range(xRg)) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    strNew = .Text
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Undo
    strOld = .Text
    .Value = strNew
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    strCmt = "Uppdated: " & Format$(Now, "YYYY/ MM/ DD ") & Chr(10) & "By: " & _
    Application.UserName & Chr(10) & "Before update : " & strOld
    If Target(1).CommentThreaded Is Nothing Then
    .AddCommentThreaded (strCmt)
    ActiveCell.CommentThreaded.Resolved = True
strCmt2 = "Updated: " & Format$(Now, "YYYY/ MM/ DD ") & Chr(10) & "By: " & _
    Application.UserName & Chr(10)
Range("AM3").Value = strCmt2
    Range("AM2").Value = Now
    Range("AM2").NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
Else
ActiveCell.ClearComments
strCmt = "Updated: " & Format$(Now, "YYYY/ MM/ DD ") & Chr(10) & "By: " & _
    Application.UserName & Chr(10) & "Before update : " & strOld
    If Target(1).CommentThreaded Is Nothing Then
    .AddCommentThreaded (strCmt)
    ActiveCell.CommentThreaded.Resolved = True
    Range("AM3").Value = strCmt2
    Range("AM2").Value = Now
    Range("AM2").NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
    
End If
End If
End With
End Sub
```

I would like to add a function so when the macro is triggered get and output the information of the first cell in the same row and column ("Name" and "Place") in a separate cell ("AM2")

I used to google, read forums but didn't find any solution

Sorry for the confusion but what i ment is Column B starting from cell B4 and downwards contains names and row 3 starting at C3 contain city names, what I would like is to display the name and the city in cell AN2 when I change a value in any cell in range C4:AK100 .
[worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eH1zu.png)

Comment: `range("AM2").value = cells(1,target.column).value & "Name & Place"` ?  The emphasis is use of the `Target.Column` or `Target.Row` when referencing the same respective item.

Comment: Not clear what you want doing in the shown code context. Do you want writing row and column in "AM2" **instread of `Now`**? If so, in which format? Something like "Name = " & row and "Place = " & column)? If not, please clarify the issue...

Comment: Anyhow, if my above supposition is correct, replace `Range("AM2").Value = Now` with `Range("AM2").Value = "Name = " & cells(target.row, 1),value) & vbLf & "Place = " & cells(1, target.column).value`. If not, please better clarify what you need.